# How can we integrate integral(s) of this type?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, hypergeometric-function

So I was able to free $dx$ from the power. Now only wolfram can solve this Integral. How can I do this on my own?

$$r=\int_0^1\left(\frac{x^{12}}{(1-x^4)^3}+1\right)^{1/4}~dx$$

Comment: May be $dx^4=(dx)^4$.

Comment: Just out of curiosity : what does WA provide as an answer ? Just a number ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Indeed, just a number. I think this is difficult to express in known constants (but I hope someone will prove that wrong). The question, which is now OK, would be magnitudes better with a context where the integral appeared. If OP has such a context, I suggest it to be included in the question. If OP also has some thoughts/tries it will be even better...

Comment: For an indefinite integral of this type, WA says "no result found in terms of standard mathematical functions". It probably did numerical integration for the above definite integral I guess.

Comment: Also WA gives a numerical value for definite integral: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E1%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E%7B12%7D%7D%7B(1-x%5E4)%5E3%7D%2B1%5Cright)%5E%7B1%2F4%7Ddx

The integral is approximately $1,698$ that can calculate with some methods of numerical analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$\int_0^1\left(\dfrac{x^{12}}{(1-x^4)^3}+1\right)^\frac{1}{4}~dx$

$=\int_0^1\left(\dfrac{x^3}{(1-x)^3}+1\right)^\frac{1}{4}~d\left(x^\frac{1}{4}\right)$

$=\dfrac{1}{4}\int_0^1x^{-\frac{3}{4}}\left(\dfrac{x^3}{(1-x)^3}+1\right)^\frac{1}{4}~dx$

$=\dfrac{1}{4}\int_1^0(1-x)^{-\frac{3}{4}}\left(\dfrac{(1-x)^3}{x^3}+1\right)^\frac{1}{4}~d(1-x)$

$=\dfrac{1}{4}\int_0^1(1-x)^{-\frac{3}{4}}\left(\dfrac{3x^2-3x+1}{x^3}\right)^\frac{1}{4}~dx$

$=\dfrac{1}{4}\int_0^1x^{-\frac{3}{4}}(1-x)^{-\frac{3}{4}}(3x^2-3x+1)^\frac{1}{4}~dx$

Which relates to [Appell Hypergeometric Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appell_series#Integral_representations)

Comment: $\displaystyle r=\dfrac{1}{4}\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{{{\left( 1-y+{{y}^{2}}\right) }^{\frac{1}{4}}}}{{{y}^{\frac{3}{4}}}\left( y+1\right) }dy$